# Criss-cross inheritance realization and EF Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, inheritance

I have a question about "criss-cross" inheritance.

Let's have some classes.

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
}

public class Notification
{
    public string Message { get; set;}
    public int NotificationType { get; set; }
}
```

These are base classes.

Now I want to create EF Core model from this.

```
public class EFUser : User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class EFNotification : Notification
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid EFUserId { get; set; }
    public EFUser EFUser { get; set; }
}
```

But as we could see, `EFUser` has a `ICollection<Notification> Notifications`, not `ICollection<EFNotification> Notifications`, so, this model could be migrated to DB. 
`virtual` keyword usage won't give me a solution, as I understand, because `public virtual ICollection<Notification> Notifications` doesn't change underlying type.

Is there any way to realize something like this construction?

Main idea of this example is a realization of "Base Structure of classes" which could be used by wrapping in EF Core object model, DTO, etc.

Comment: Even if it could be done it would create a tight coupling between your data model and the domain model (which I guess it is). Not recommended, at all. Keep them apart and use mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good use case for generics

```
public class User<TNotification> where TNotification : Notification {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TNotification> Notifications { get; set; }
}
```

A default `User` class is basically a `User<Notification>`

For example

```
public class User : User<Notification> {
    //Which works out to having
    //public ICollection<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
}
```

Having the generic base class now allows for

```
public class EFUser : User<EFNotification> {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Which would mean that the `EFUser` would now have a `ICollection<EFNotification> Notifications` property.

Comment: Thank you much! That's the solution I was looking for! It's a witting decision to use tight coupling, because I could connect domain model and data transfer model with the same base and implement models tuning by fluent api or Map.Ignore. And, of couse, domain model and data transfer model are connected together by AutoMapper. So, each modification of fundamental classes automatically changes all derived classes and mappings between domain model and data transfer model. Hope, I explained my idea clearly.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest creating a completely separate entity classes instead. Then map to/from your model classes.

```cs
public class EFUser
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EFNotification> Notifications { get; set; }
}

public class Mapper // or use AutoMapper
{
    public EFUser Map(User user)
    {
        return new EFUser
        {
            UserName = user.UserName,
            Notifications = Map(user.Notifications)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this solution and I want to wide/improve it, because I'll need to write mapping for each bridge between classes in my project (for example, for Request and Response classes and so on).

Comment: Also it should use huge overhead for deep inheritance structures.